# React-Admin: Access record.id inside Show View component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm trying something with looks simple, but I don't get it, even after many searches.

What I want to do is pass the record.id as an argument to a function, like this:
(The function is `ClientShowGroupSum`)

```
export const ClientsShow = props => {
    const classes = useStyles(); 
    const chartDataThisYear = ClientShowGroupSum(null, "other", record.id)

    return (
        <Show actions={<ShowActions />} {...props}>
            <TabbedShowLayout >
                <Tab label="Principal">
                    <SimpleLineChart
                      chartTitle="Faturamento R$"
                      mylabels={ chartDataThisYear.chartlabels } // using data here
                      myvalues={ chartDataThisYear.chartvalues } // using data here                       
                      tooltipXpre={"Data: "}
                      tooltipYpre={"R$"} />
                </Tab>
            </TabbedShowLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `id` in the `props`:

`const chartDataThisYear = ClientShowGroupSum(null, "other", props.id)`

Comment: wow... it was really simple. I was trying record.id and other things :(
Thanks for your very fast response.